# ASP.net WEB API CORS 404 error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, cors

I create a Windows Service with a integrated ASP.net Host and WEB API.
The host and API works fine. When I use my internet Browser I get response
from my controller, so no permission problems.

WebService configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCors();
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowAll"));
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("")]
public class TimerController : Controller
{
public static List<Timer> timers = new List<Timer> { };

// url:localhost:48523
public IEnumerable<Timer> GetAllTimers()
{
    return timers;
}
}
```

Now I try to use CORS to get the information from the WEB API.
For the CORS request I used JavaScript.

```
var json;
var url = "http://192.168.87.58:48523";

function sendRequest()
{
    json = new XMLHttpRequest();
    json.open("GET", url, true);
    json.send();
    console.log(json.responseText);
}
```

But if I try to get response I get the error: 404 File not Found with follow note:

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location:
>   http://192.168.87.58:48523/ Line Number 1, Column 1:

If I open up this page I get the raw data view:

> [{"computerName":"XX-XX-XX-XX-XX","computerIP":"192.168.XX.XX","lastLogin":"2017-XX-29T16:XX:XX.438988+02:00","plannedShutdownTime":"2017-XX-02T09:XX:XX.438988+02:00","isRunning":true,"hoursToSleep":48.0}]

If I take a look in the header information, it is everything fine.
[Header information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I811w.png)
I need help, I can't find any bug.

Comment: CORS errors are typically 405, 404 means a location problem.  Your url looks suspect, you don't have an API path behind it, try adding that.

Answer (score 1):

I think your cors configuration is not correct. Web client and web api connections are different so I understand your problem.

I'm writing our configuration below so you can check it.

### **ASP.NET (OWIN)**

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors -Version 3.1.0
```

Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)
```

Web Config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

### **ASP.NET (System.Web)**

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

App_Start/WebApiConfig - Register method:

```
config.EnableCors();
```

FooController:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```