# Even after adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin setting in web.config still getting the No Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

Hi i have an ajax call to web api, i have added the setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in web.config file, but still i am getting same error while calling the api.
can anyone help me ...

my web.config setting is

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

my ajax call is

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:62607/api/Values',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            async: true,
            responseType: 'json',
            success:
                function (data) {
});
```

Comment: Which version of Web API are you using? If it is >=2.0, then this is the recommended way of enabling CORS in Web API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: I have enabled cors as mentioned din the document, still it is not working

Comment: Try adding: <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" /> as well in the web.config

Comment: i have added that also, But still it is not working.
Actually my web api is another project and ajax call is in another project

Comment: Remove CORS configuration from web.config and see my answer. For testing CORS, you do need the javascript ajax call to be in another project.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

you don't need any settings in the web.config. The least you need to enable CORS is to follow these 3 steps:

1. Install this package with nuget: ***Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors***
2. In App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs, add this line as first line in the Register method: ***config.EnableCors();***
3. Add this attribute in your values controller: [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
   so the controller looks like this:

   [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

   public class ValuesController : ApiController
   {...}

Comment: I have tried your answer also but still unable to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web api cors, see my answer:

**[ASP.net WEB API CORS 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845735/asp-net-web-api-cors-404-error/44851174#44851174)**

**Basically - Owin**

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors -Version 3.1.0
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)
```

Web Config

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

if you need system.web, see my answer.