# Wep API 2 calls with authorization header gives 403 error

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api application that works good on the local network ( intranet), and it works on the internet also as long as the calls with no authorization header.

All calls with Authorization header gives the following error:

> 403 Forbidden ( The server denied the specified Uniform Resource
>   Locator (URL). Contact the server administrator.

What I tried so far

I added the package

> Install-Package Microsoft,.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

When I add Authorization : Bearer `The Token` , the method returns 403

How to solve this

Comment: Do you send token information in header?

Comment: If the call is being done from a Web Browser to a server, please use Chrome Developer Tools, "Network" tab (or maybe other browsers have it too) to see what is the exact HTTP request content (including headers) that you are sending out, and then please post that here.

Comment: yes, I am testing using post man and the token call works and it returns the access_token, but the method `api/loaddata` when I add the access_token to the header, it returns the 403, all calls without authorization works fine

Comment: Can you take a look at this  ?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845735/asp-net-web-api-cors-404-error/44851174#44851174

Comment: i tried that solution already, I think the problem not in enabling the cors, because if I call any method with no `[Authorize]` it works fine, only methods that are decorated with the `[Authorize]` they returns 403. They works on the local network but fails on the real ip

Comment: You are authenticated, but not authorized for the action. If it works locally but not in production then there is an issue with permissions on your user account.

Comment: on local network, it returns `json` data as desired, but when accessing the web api from internet it doesn't @Crowcoder

Comment: May pay looking at the [substatus](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0--iis-7-5--and-iis-8-0) A way to reproduce your particular issue could help solve the problem. 403 can be received for any number of reasons, and it's not clear from your existing description which it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the details you provides, It is clear that you have a firewall preventing this type of requests.

For example the `Forefront TMG` method to the published web server:

1. No delegation, and the client cannot authenticate directly
2. No delegation, but client may authenticate directly

You should use the second option and you will be Good

Hope this will help you